# Remove last characters from a string in C#. An elegant way?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a numeric string like this `2223,00`.  I would like to transform it to `2223`. This is: without the information **after** the "**,**". Assume that there will be only two decimals after the "**,**".

I did:

```
str = str.Remove(str.Length - 3, 3);
```

Is there a more elegant solution? Maybe using another function? -I don´t like putting explicit numbers-

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can actually just use the Remove overload that takes one parameter:

```
str = str.Remove(str.Length - 3);
```

However, if you're trying to avoid hard coding the length, you can use:

```
str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf(','));
```

Comment: I received a lot of good answers. But this one is the one I will use, in terms of elegance. Nevertheless, I don´t know, in **low level**, which one is more efficient. So, make your choice!

Comment: The second solution is way easier to read, understand, and maintain, and in terms of **low level** performance, the difference is incredibly insignificant.
If you KNOW that the `,` is always at position -3, then the first solution is still OK, but *premature optimization* is a terrible thing to waste your time on.

Comment: @Kani The first is the most efficient - but I completely agree with Scott.  I would always choose the second, unless I knew, after profiling, that there was a perf. bottleneck here.  Both of these (and most of the other answers) are going to be very fast -good enough for nearly all purposes.

Comment: Suppose you want the string to be unmodified if there's no comma?

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps this:

```
str = str.Split(",").First();
```

Comment: I think this is the "most elegant" of the answers - at least so far.

Comment: what do you thing about the @ ReedCopsey one? I think is a very good one.

Comment: @Kani: in terms of elegance I find most of the answers posted *good enough*. I wouldn't be bothered with performance either, *unless* it really proves to be bottleneck. Only thing to consider is how do you want to deal with strings coming in different format...

Comment: Consider passing a second argument of `2` to `Split` because you don't care about any further commas.

Answer (score 5):

This will return to you a string excluding everything after the comma

```
str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(','));
```

Of course, this *assumes* your string actually has a comma with decimals.  The above code will fail if it doesn't.  You'd want to do more checks:

```
commaPos = str.IndexOf(',');
if(commaPos != -1)
    str = str.Substring(0, commaPos)
```

I'm assuming you're working with a string to begin with.  Ideally, if you're working with a number to begin with, like a float or double, you could just cast it to an `int`, then do `myInt.ToString()` like:

```
myInt = (int)double.Parse(myString)
```

This parses the double using the current culture (here in the US, we use `.` for decimal points).  However, this again assumes that your input string is can be parsed.

Answer (score 4):

```
String.Format("{0:0}", 123.4567);      // "123"
```

If your initial value is a decimal into a string, you will need to convert

```
String.Format("{0:0}", double.Parse("3.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))  //3.5
```

In this example, I choose Invariant culture but you could use the one you want.

I prefer using the Formatting function because you never know if the decimal may contain 2 or 3 leading number in the future.

Edit: You can also use `Truncate` to remove all after the , or .

```
Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal("3,5")));
```

Comment: Well, I´m getting the same number in this case, whit the **coma** on it.

Comment: What is the exact string you use and what culture is your computer?

Comment: Like in the example: **dddd,dd** , where **d** is a digit. The decimals are after the **,** in this case. I´m standardizing some results, deleting **.** and **,**, or using **.** instead of **,**

Comment: I don't know if I would use string.Format to do this personally.  While it works, it winds up boxing the double before its passed to string.Format, thus creating an extra object.

Comment: I have to say that I do not know what is better in term of performance between playing with String (substring) or boxing. I do not think it really matter if it's not used intensively. Depend of the situation :)

Comment: @Daok, I totally agree, boxing only really matters if this were used in a large loop for example, since a new object would be allocated each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Since C# 8.0 it has been possible to do this with a [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges).

```
string textValue = "2223,00";
textValue = textValue[0..^3];
Console.WriteLine(textValue);
```

This would output the string `2223`.

The `0` says that it should start from the zeroth position in the string

The `..` says that it should take the range between the operands on either side

The `^` says that it should take the operand relative to the end of the sequence

The `3` says that it should end from the third position in the string

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cut End. "12".SubstringFromEnd(1) -> "1"
    /// </summary>
    public static string SubstringFromEnd(this string value, int startindex)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
        return value.Substring(0, value.Length - startindex);
    }
}
```

I prefer an extension method here for two reasons:

1. I can chain it with Substring.
     `Example: f1.Substring(directorypathLength).SubstringFromEnd(1)`
2. Speed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LastIndexOf and Substring combined to get all characters to the left of the last index of the comma within the sting.

string var = var.Substring(0, var.LastIndexOf(','));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TrimEnd`. It's efficient as well and looks clean.

```
"Name,".TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: That will only remove any ',' characters that are at the end of the string.  Since the string "123,45" ends with digits, `"123,45".TrimEnd(',')` will return "123,45".

Comment: `Remove last characters from a string if this character is... ` Just fits me well. Appreciated. `"oppa/   ".Trim().TrimEnd('/');`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It worked for me:

```
str = str.Split(',').Last();
```

Answer (score -3):

Use lastIndexOf. Like:

```
string var = var.lastIndexOf(',');
```

Comment: var is a variable name.  It should never be used as a name for a string.  -1;  additionally this only gives the index, so it only solves part of the problem.  You need the Remove().