# Remove char at a specific place, counted from the end of a string

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to remove a character from inside a string, say, 3 spaces from the end. I'm using this to act as typing on a screen in a game in unity, think like a text editor, where you can use the arrow keys to move the cursor inside of the string to remove characters. For example,

```
"Hello World!"
```

After pressing left arrow 3 times (I know how to increase/decrease this number obviously, just not where to put the '3'), and then pressing backspace, it should become:

```
"Hello Wold!"
```

Currently I am using .Remove(0, text.Length - 1) (Didn't just copy/paste this code so might be a bit off, just memory) to remove characters from the end, but I don't believe that will work for this. Thank you for any help you give!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098556/remove-last-characters-from-a-string-in-c-an-elegant-way The answer I like best, myself, is the accepted answer here -- you can avoid hardcoding the number.

Comment: "I don't believe that will work for this" .... did you tried it ?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't very clear but I did try it, just missed the solution to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `String.Remove` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes the starting point and number of characters to be removed:

```
string str = "Hello World!";
string resultStr = str.Remove(str.Length - 4, 1);
```

Make sure to check the string length first.

Comment: Thanks, tried something similar but I got it backwards. And yes, I will have to make sure that it doesn't decrease past the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```
var text = "Hello World!";
var index = 3;
text.Remove(text.Length - index - 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use Substring.

```
substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

e.g

```
String s = substring(0, s.length()-3);//removes the last 3 strings.
```